# Can a US citizen with a long term residency card from Spain work in Iceland?

Tags: residency, iceland

My 23 year old son is an American citizen with a US passport. We have been living in Spain for the past 9 years and have a long term residency with the right to work.

Can he work in Iceland because he is a long term resident of Spain and has a residency card that authorizes him to work?

Comment: Work in Iceland and taking up residence there as well? Provided he has only US citizenship and is not a national of a Schengen member country, then I suggest reading [this](https://island.is/en/permit-based-on-work) and [this](https://island.is/en/general-info-on-work-permits) for a start.

Answer (score 2):

Your son would need to get a residence permit from Iceland, a process that should be fairly straightforward under the relevant EU directive, but the Spanish card itself does not authorize employment outside of Spain.